# css menu display hidden div underneath hovered link

Tags: jquery, css, menu, submenu

I am trying to create a CSS/Jquery horizontal menu. All of the list items include a link and one will include a hidden div which should be displayed when the corresponding link is hovered over.

The problem I am having is when the link is hovered over the hidden div is in the container div of the menu, meaning the background of the now displayed div is the same as the menu, and other styles.

What I would like is for the div which is to be displayed, is not part of the same div as the menu but which appears beneath the corresponding link.

An example I found is http://www.inprocorp.com/default.aspx if you hover over any of the header links.

The content in the hidden div could contain images, HTML lists, paragraphs...

I tried to use jsfiddler but it is down at the moment.

Code:

HTML

```
<div id="centeredmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">services</a></li>
<li class="subMenu"><a href="#" id="prod">products</a>
<div class="hiddencontent">hidden content</li>
<li><a href="#">contact</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">about</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('li.subMenu a').hover(function(evt)
{       
var link = $(this);
var dialog = link.next('div');
dialog.css("top", link.position().top);
dialog.css("left", link.position().left);
dialog.css("position", "relative"); 
dialog.show();
},

function() { 
$(this).next('div').hide();
})
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Why do you need JQuery for this?

Comment: If it can be done in pure CSS then sure, but I have yet to find an example which positioned the menu where I wanted it.

Comment: It looks like div.hiddencontent is missing its closing tag </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should help you out:

http://www.brandammo.co.uk/blog/2011/02/simple-jquery-dropdown-menu-with-easing-and-hoverintent-navidropdown-1-0/

To create drop-down menus hoverintent is one of the most useful plugins - trust me!

The demo is also similar to the effect you want to achieve (without the easing)

http://www.brandammo.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/jquery.naviDropDown.v1.0.DEMO/